# Firebase query by date string

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know that it's possible to query by timestamp as seen in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908318/firebase-query-by-date-range), However, what if the date is in the following format:

```
{
  "lambeosaurus": {
     "date" : "2012-20-03",
     "length" : 12.5,
     "weight": 5000
  },
 "stegosaurus": {
     "date" : "2015-25-13",
     "length" : 9,
     "weight" : 2500
  }
}
```

How would I go about and query this by date?

Answer (score 5):

You've stored your dates as strings. When Firebase order strings it uses lexicographic ordering. In that order, `"2012-20-03"` comes before `"2012-25-01"`.

This is the reason why the question you linked to (and the Firebase documentation) usually store dates as [timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp). Those have all the information about the date, in a single number that is guaranteed to be ordered correctly.

Alternatively, you can store the date as a string. But in that case you have to make sure the date is in a format that will lexicographically order correctly too. For your sample that would be: `"2012-01-25"` and `"2012-03-20"`.

So in this case your only option is to change the data structure to either what was in the original question (and documentation) or to a string format that orders in the order you want.

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to timestamp :

```
new Date('2012-20-03'.split('-').reverse().join('/')).getTime()
```

In general :

```
   function toTimeStamp(dateString){
       return new Date(dateString.split('-').reverse().join('/')).getTime()

   }
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to convert all those dates on firebase before I can query it?

Comment: Give me github URL of firebase , and , i will rectify the source code to support this syntax  : 
`orderByChild(function(e){return new Date(e.date.split('-').........).getTime()})`

Comment: I made a dummy firebase with some dummy data:https://epilog-a3e16.firebaseio.com/flights.json