# How to use orderBy when DATE is stored in String format

Tags: android, date, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using Firebase, the Date is stored as : dd/MM/yyyy in the Firebase DB in String format.
I'm not getting desired results when using orderBy to order my entries by date.

```
dbInstance.orderByChild("eventDate").startAt(currentDate).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

This is what I'm using to display entries. It works fine. But the problem is with dates not being sorted correctly.

[image]

So, if today is 02/05/17 , entry with date in the above image won't display because on comparing these two strings, the one in the image is smaller.

How can this be corrected? Please help!!

Comment: Don't store your dates as a String

Comment: I think it's better to parse it as time not string.

Comment: When you query strings, Firebase will order items lexicographically. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216858/firebase-query-by-date-string/38226376#38226376

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to save your data as a `TIMESTAMP` like this: `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` and not as a String.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
ref.child("yourNode").updateChildren(map);
```

And to get the data back, i suggest you use this method:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```

To solve your problem, you only need to create a query based on the correct `DatabaseReference` and than `orderByValue("timestamp");`

Hope it helps.