# Flutter Firestore search from more than 1 collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So what I'm trying to do is search from 2 or more collection. Here's my collection :

```
Tier-1
Tier-2
Tier-3
```

Let's say I want to search with key "name" and what I want to achieve is, it will searching from Tier-1 to
Tier-3. If there's no document equal to "name" from Tier-1, it will continue to Tier-2, if there's document equal to "name" at Tier-2, it will stop and return the document. Is it possible to achieve? or my logic is totally wrong

Comment: Sure, it sounds possible.  You will execute a query for each collection until you find what you're looking for.

Comment: Yea I'm just a bit confused because I'm new to this noSQL things. So basically if it return null, it will execute another query right? until it found what user looking for. Thanks for commenting tho, I might delete this question later lmao

Comment: Your sub/collections are named Tier-n or they have the same name?

Comment: Tier-n because maybe I could loop it and then after it found what user looking for, I'll just break it. Will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you are saying, is that you have the following structure:

```
Tier-1 (collection) -> docId(document) -> Tier-2 (collection) -> docId(document) -> Tier-3 (collection) -> docId(document)
```

You can do the following:

```
  void getData() {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection("Tier-1")
        .where("name", isEqualTo: "peter")
        .getDocuments()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
        if (result.exists) {
          print(result.data);
        } else {
          Firestore.instance
              .collectionGroup("Tier-2")
              .where("name", isEqualTo: "peter")
              .getDocuments()
              .then((querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
              if (result.exists) {
                print(result.data);
              } else {
                Firestore.instance
                    .collectionGroup("Tier-3")
                    .where("name", isEqualTo: "peter")
                    .getDocuments()
                    .then((querySnapshot) {
                  querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
                    if (result.exists) {
                      print(result.data);
                    } else {}
                  });
                });
              }
            });
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

First you check the top collection `Tier-1`, if it returns no result, then you need to check the subcollection `Tier-2`

Comment: If i use isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:, will it work just fine?, or there will be perfomance issues or etc . I'm sorry Firestore is new thing for me

Comment: isGreaterThanOrEqualTo is different than isequalto, firebase uses the `lexicographic ordering` for strings for explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38226376/7015400, so you have to check if you are doing it correctly or no, but regarding performance issue its the same as isequalto you are querying the collection

Comment: for tutorial firebase with flutter, check my blog https://petercoding.com