# Retrieve firebase data within a range of 1 week

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-calendar

I want to retrieve Firebase data within a range of say 1 week. I can query and get data for a day like today, but how about for a range of say 1 week? This is the code that am currenly using for retrieving data for a given day

```
String mDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("expenses").child(onlineUserId);
    Query query = reference.orderByChild("date").equalTo(mDate);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            myDataList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Data data = snapshot.getValue(Data.class);
                myDataList.add(data);

            }
            todayItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I cannot find a way of retrieving data for a given range. Someone please help.
[image]

Comment: for that you have to get record and query it manually on front end.

Comment: I now want to know how I can do it programatically

Comment: simply get all record first then iterate and get result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Realtime Database is not designed for complex SQL-like queries.

Not sure if your question refers to grouping results by week. If all you need is a set of results that start and on a certain date and end on another date, you can use `startAt(...)` and `endAt(...)` like described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909505/5707212) or [the spec](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#java).

If you need anything more complex than that, you need to

1. either take all results and filter them in your front end/app code
2. or use a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to do the filtering on the server and
   passing the results to the front end.
3. (Not recommended) You can record the week number (i.e. 45_2020) as a separate field in the document, and filter by that. It's messy and you would have to trust that the front end enters correct info in the field.